# javascript_include_tag file is missing on the production environment ( 404 )

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

On the development environment (with `therubyracer`) all works great. Now I set nginx + passenger to run my rails app for the production environment. All works fine except one (slides_index.js) file for which I get 404.

That file contains jQuery code which **has to be run just on one page**.
To do so I use `<%= javascript_include_tag "slides_index" %>` on that page.

I run `rake assets:precompile` which created `public/assets/application-1774b3421bf0b4433ea3628c1c5dce38.js`. There is no any other .js file in the that path, especially no **slides_index.js** (that one is in `app/assets/javascripts/`).

It's quite obvious that if there's not **slides_index.js** in the `public/assets/` path than I get 404 for it. The question is why it works fine with `therubyracer` (development environment) and how to fix it in a proper way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Rails only compiles application.js as a standalone file.  You can add other files to be compiled in config/application.rb with `config.assets.precompile`, so add the `slides_index`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['slides_index.js']
```